# Getting "resolve: Host not found (authoritative)" exception when using boost asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm trying to create a simple proxy server. I want to connect to a remote `host_` (could be something like google.com) at `port_`, and forward a request `req_buf_to_send`. The following is my code:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(host_, port_string, boost::asio::ip::resolver_query_base::numeric_service);
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::socket socket(io_service);
tcp::endpoint connectionEndpoint(endpoint_iterator->endpoint().address(), port_);
boost::system::error_code ec;
socket.connect(connectionEndpoint, ec);
boost::asio::write(socket, req_buf_to_send);
```

When I run the above and send it a request that it needs to forward, the code fails and an exception is thrown:

`Exception: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)`

I also have a unit test for the above code and that fails too, saying:

`C++ exception with description "resolve: Service not found" thrown in the test body.`

So, it seems as though there is a problem in my resolver logic. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the host or service is unknown or empty. Here are a few demonstrations of how the resolver will fail depending on the inputs:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/range/istream_range.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(io);

    for (auto q : {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query 
            // these are good:
            {"google.com", ""},              // port 0
            {"google.com", "ftp"},           // port 21
            {"google.com", "80"},            // port 80
            // these ar bad:
            {"google.ggg", ""},              // host not found
            {"google.com", "bogus_service"}, // service not found
            {"google.com", "-1"},            // service not found
            {"", ""},                        // host not found
        })
    {
        try
        {
            for (auto ep : boost::make_iterator_range(r.resolve(q), {}))
                std::cout << std::quoted(q.host_name()) << " -> " << ep.endpoint() << "\n";
        } catch(std::exception const& e) {
            std::cout << std::quoted(q.host_name()) << " " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
"google.com" -> 172.217.168.206:0
"google.com" -> [2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e]:0
"google.com" -> 172.217.168.206:21
"google.com" -> [2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e]:21
"google.com" -> 172.217.168.206:80
"google.com" -> [2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e]:80
"google.ggg" resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
"google.com" resolve: Service not found
"google.com" resolve: Service not found
"" resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
```

Now if your system doesn't know the service names that could be because you run on some stripped-down minimalist install (a docker container or embedded system?). Solutions are to install a standard service database (e.g. put the IANA list in `/etc/services`.

> On a Debian it would be a matter of `sudo apt-get install netbase`